# python dictionary with list as values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of string like

```
vals = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',........]
```

using `vals`, I would be making a request to a server with each vals[i]. The server would return me a number for each of the vals.

it could be 1 for 'a', 2 for 'b', 1 again for 'c', 2 again for 'd', and so on.
Now I want to create a dictionary that should look like

```
{ 1: ['a','c'], 2:['b','d'], 3: ['e'], ..... }
```

What is the quickest possible way to achieve this? Could I use `map()` somehow?
I mean I can try doing this by storing the results of request in a separate list and then map them one by one - but I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work, using [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
results = {}
for val in vals:
    i = some_request_to_server(val)
    results.setdefault(i, []).append(val)
```

`results.setdefault(i, []).append(val)` is equivalent in behavior to the following code:

```
if i in results:
    results[i].append(val)
else:
    results[i] = [val]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `defaultdict` from `collections` like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict
results = defaultdict(list)
for val in vals:
    i = some_request_to_server(val)
    results[i].append(val)
```